# Packet Arrival time Drifting Linearly at the Receiving Endpoint

Tags: c, networking, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, packet-injection

I have two Linux machines connected to each other by 10G NIC Card, on one machine I have a pcap file where i am sending the packets using libpcap in C Code based on the packet interval compared to first packet present in the pcap file, then i am doing tcpdump for the incoming packets on the different machine into a pcap file, now the packet interval time is as expected to original at the start of few 100 packets, then the difference starts increasing linearly, any idea why?
I also did tcpdump on the transmitting side there the time drift is not seen.

Sending side pcap file comparison
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohD2h.png)

capture side pcap file comparison
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N22Vg.png)

Expected was acceptable difference, but getting linear drift

Comment: What is "packet interval time"?  If the receiving side can't keep up (i.e. write i/o) it will get progressive slower.  What does iostat say?

Comment: the packet arrival time difference with respect to 1st arrival packet is the packet interval, can you please tell how to do IO stat along with the tcpdump?

Comment: I get it's a difference between what?  Are we talking timestamp of the first package in a series or something else?  You should revise the question with a crisp definition of what you are measuring and on what host.  You would run `iostat 3 3` in separate shell on the machine and see if the disks are storage is busy.

Comment: the packet interval is in comparison of epoch time of incoming packets to the epoch time of first packet, i am sending the packets using libpcap in Ubuntu VM server where this device is connected to 10G NIC card, now the other end of the NIC card connected to CentOS device, where i am using tcpdump tool to capture the incoming packets into a pcap file
i did iostat 3 3 along with the program, this is what i got

Comment: Linux 5.18.14-xanmod1 (bras)    18/12/23        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                    0.04    0.01     0.06           0.08    0.00      99.81

Comment: Device             tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_dscd/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn    kB_dscd
sda               1.80         7.93        17.25         0.00     696365    1513689          0


avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
                  21.35    0.00      0.25         0.00    0.00      78.40

Comment: Please update the question with requested data (and delete the comments which are hard to read)